# 301 Redirect for URLs with % percentage mark on htacess

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I neee to redirect

`http://www.example.com.au/recipes/recipe.aspx?name=91-Sunflower%20Crackers`

to `https://www.example.com.au/recipes/`

I followed so many posts but this is not redirecting at all.

This is my code

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=91-Sunflower%20Crackers$
RewriteRule ^/recipes/recipe\.aspx?$ /recipes/? [NE,L,R]
```

What is the error here ?

Answer (score 1):

This rule should work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^name=91-Sunflower(\s|%20)Crackers$" [NC]
RewriteRule ^recipes/recipe\.aspx?$ /recipes/? [NC,L,R]
```

No leading slash in `RewriteRule` and use `(\s|%20)` in `RewriteCond` to match a whitespace.